# Print form in Windows Mobile 6 application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-phone, compact-framework

I am working on an application for Windows Mobile 6 in visual studio 2008 with Compact framework 3.5. I want to add a print button on the form to print the data displayed on that form using c#. I searched the code and I come to know that it can be done by using "System.Drawing.Printing assembly". 
I tried to use that but it is saying "The type or namespace name 'Printing' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
Same error message is coming by using "System.ComponentModel.Component".
The reason for this error is the System.Drawing.dll file.
How can i resolve this error or any other way to implement print code.
I am using trial version of Visual Studio 2008 professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact Framework is not the same as the Full Desktop Framework, it lacks many classes.

Despite from that, Windows Mobile has NO printing support like the desktop windows. There is no print driver, no spooling etc.

You may use direct printing language coding (ie using HP PCL5 language) or one of the various printing libraries for Compact Framework like PrinterCE for example.